# filtering one array from another with ngif

Tags: html, angular

I have two arrays. The first array contain rows in table one of this row name department id and one row has a selection (transfer to another department which contain the second array)

now transfer to should filter to not contain the same first array department, pic may explain more.

when i add `*ngIf="DepartmentDTO.dept_id != ALLREQUEST.dept"`
i got the list but come null value with list, pic show.

also i if possible to get the list with other filter which 
`*ngIf="DepartmentDTO.dept_id != ALLREQUEST.dept ; DepartmentDTO.dept_id != 0"`

**Expected Output**

[image: Expected Output]

**Current Output**

[image: Current Output]

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let DepartmentDTO of depts">
      <label><input class="input1" name="radio" ng-control="depts" type="radio" [value]="DepartmentDTO.dept_id" [(ngModel)]="deptId" (click)="getClinicTotal(DepartmentDTO.dept_id)">
        {{DepartmentDTO.dept_name}}<br>
      </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
TotalCount ={{total_count}}
<br> Department _id:= {{deptId}} all:= {{all}}, Triage:= {{triage}} , clinics:= {{clinics}} , gb:= {{gb}} , dentail:= {{dentail}}. selectedRow = {{selectedRow}}


<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>qid</th>
      <th>qno</th>
      <th>dept</th>
      <th>Tocken For</th>
      <th>Transfer to</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let ALLREQUEST of AllRequest;let i = index">
    <tr *ngIf="deptId==0 || deptId== ALLREQUEST.dept">
      <td>
        {{ALLREQUEST.qid}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ALLREQUEST.qno}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ALLREQUEST.dept}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ALLREQUEST.dept_name}}
      </td>

      <td>
        <select type="list" name="action" [(ngModel)]="ALLREQUEST.transfer_to" [disabled]="!ALLREQUEST.isEditable">
          <option *ngFor="let DepartmentDTO of depts " [value]="DepartmentDTO.dept_id">
            <tr *ngIf="DepartmentDTO.dept_id!=ALLREQUEST.dept">{{DepartmentDTO.dept_name}}</tr>
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button (click)="ALLREQUEST.isEditable=!ALLREQUEST.isEditable" *ngIf="!ALLREQUEST.isEditable" class="btn btn-primary">Action</button>
        <button *ngIf="ALLREQUEST.isEditable" (click)="transferToken(ALLREQUEST.qid,ALLREQUEST.transfer_to)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example please?

Answer (score 0):

i got list
now how can i put it in selection list?

```js
     getDept(indx:number){
  let array1= this.depts;
  let array2= this.AllRequest;
  
  var array = array2.map(function(e) {
    var f = array1.filter(a => a.dept_id != e.dept && a.dept_id != 0);    
    
    return f.map(function(a) {return a.dept_name;}); //? f.dept_id : 0  
  });
  console.log(array[indx]);   
}
```